# 301 Redirect Full URL

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt, http-redirect

How do I create a redirect so that http://fullurl/store redirects to
https://fullurl/store

Do I do this in htaccess or robots?

Comment: when I say redirects to https://fullurl/store I mean without the www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`robots.txt` is used only for telling search engine bots and other crawlers how to deal with your URL structure, it has nothing to do with redirecting the user.

To force HTTPS on a site, add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the web root of `fullurl` (or inside the root of `store` to redirect only that directory to HTTPS):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Its WordPress WooCommerce

Comment: Also I am already forcing the https and I have taken care of the www issue to force the SSL  The issue is google indexed a link that is in this context http://thisismyfullurlwithWWW.com/store and I want that particular link to rediret to https://thisismyurlwithoutWWW.com/store

Comment: the first is http the second is https

Comment: That's got nothing to do with redirecting. You must tell Google using the Webmaster Tools which URL to prefer.